# Output redirection locking file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a simple batch script to test an exe application. The start command redirects the 'main.exe' output to a txt file. When the exe does not work, the script works well. The problem is when the exe run successfully, it seems that test.txt gets locked. The obtained error is as follows::

"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Here follows the script.

```
@echo %date% 1> test.txt
@start "" "cmd /c .\dist\main\main.exe 1>> test.txt 2>&1"
@timeout /t 10
@taskkill /f /im main.exe 1>> test.txt 2>&1
```

Even after kill main.exe process, test.txt remains locked. Is there any way to unlock test.txt?

Comment: Why are you using `start` to run `cmd` to run an `.exe` file? there is no need for `cmd` here, which is maybe the process that locks the file…

Comment: Is the goal to kill `main.exe` if it runs longer than ten (10) seconds?

Answer (score 0):

`main.exe` locks the file. If after the 10-second timeout, `main.exe` is still running, then the file is still locked, so `taskkill` can't open it, hence it will fail.

Try redirecting `taskkill` to a different file.